# Istio checking what is installed

Tags: kubernetes, istio

The istio docs [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/istioctl/#check-what-s-installed) has the following information:

> The istioctl command saves the IstioOperator CR that was used to
> install Istio in a copy of the CR named installed-state. You can
> inspect this CR if you lose track of what is installed in a cluster.
>
> The installed-state CR is also used to perform checks in some istioctl
> commands and should therefore not be removed.

Now, I would like to know is what is "CR" and how to inspect this "CR" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Short answer

this will give you all deployed objects belongs to Istio CRs in all namespaces:

```
kubectl api-resources | grep -i istio | awk '{print $4}' | while read cr; do
    kubectl get $(echo $cr | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]') --all-namespaces
done
```

### Details:

CR is a general k8s terminology and it means `Custom Resource`.
And its definition is named CRD : Custom Resource Definition.

So we have two category of resources:

- Built-in Resources: Pod, Service, Deployment, Ingress, ReplicaSet, StatefulSet,...
- Custom Resources(CR): which depends on your customization of your cluster.

  - For example if you install Istio, you will get CRs like : IstioOperator, ...
  - If you install Prometheus-Operator, you will get CRs like: Alertmanager, PrometheusRule, ...

Now to get the list of resources whether are built-in or custom (CR) , run:

```
kubectl api-resources | awk '{print $4}'
```

Filter them to resources belongs to Istio

```
kubectl api-resources | grep -i istio | awk '{print $4}'
```

Now because `IstioOperator` (for example) is a resource, you can run the following:

```
kubectl get istiooperator
```

Check objects belongs to this CR in all namespaces

```
kubectl get istiooperator --all-namespaces
```

All commands above will help you to build a YAML object based on the existing resources. Actually, it will help you in `kind: ???` field

If you want also to get the suitable `apiVersion: ???`, check `kubectl api-versions`